# Bitwise & | operators in octal system

Tags: php, bitwise-operators

I understand how bitwise operator `&` and `|` work for binary numbers. However I'm confused at how they work with octal numbers.

Does the system convert the number to binary first and then perform the operation and then convert back to octal? Or is it variable?

For example if I do either of these:

```
echo decoct( 0400 & 0500 | 0000 );
echo decoct( 0600 & 0500 | 0000 );
```

I get `400` as the result.

However, if i do:

```
echo decoct( 0400 & 0500 | 0100 );
echo decoct( 0600 & 0500 | 0100 );
```

I get `500` in both cases.

Also, I have seen code where the bitwise operation in PHP without using `decoct` around it. Does PHP retain it as octal after completion of the operation? or converts it to decimal (and when does it do that?).

Kindly guide me in the right direction to what to study and learn to understand octal (and decimal and others) bitwise operations.

Answer (score 1):

The bitwise operators "luckily" work for binary, octal and hexadecimal presentations of your values/variables. In the end they all will run on a binary level on your values/variables. The grouping of your digits/bits fits perfectly with the bitwise operators.

```
  0400 = 0b100000000 = 0x100 (0001 0000 0000)
& 0500 = 0b101000000 = 0x140 (0001 0100 0000)
----------------------------
  0400 = 0b100000000 = 0x100 (0001 0000 0000)
| 0100 = 0b001000000 = 0x040 (0000 0100 0000)
----------------------------
  0500 = 0b101000000 = 0x140 (0001 0100 0000)
```

And for the other expression:

```
  0600 = 0b110000000 = 0x180 (0001 1000 0000)
& 0500 = 0b101000000 = 0x140 (0001 0100 0000)
----------------------------
  0400 = 0b100000000 = 0x100 (0001 0000 0000)
| 0100 = 0b001000000 = 0x040 (0000 0100 0000)
----------------------------
  0500 = 0b101000000 = 0x140 (0001 0100 0000)
```

It does works for these representations because a "digit" will always use 1, 3 or 4 bits and no other "digit" can overwrite these "reserved" digits.

The bitwise operations are run on the bits of the values (hence the name). The representation/display of the values are irrelevant for the bitwise operations.

Comment: thanks for nicely explaining it. Can you also explain the other part of question that how does php know we're dealing with oct or dec numbers there and why some scripts dnt use decoct too?

Comment: @NabeelKhan The representation of a variable doesn't change the value of the variable. PHP knows when you deal with oct or dec numbers when you use the prefix `0` for oct and `0x` for hex numbers. If you want to use `dechex()` and such methods depends on how you want to print or read strings/numbers, but it has no affect on the bitwise operations.